# Show that if $F(x,y,z)$ is an irreducible homogenous polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$, then $F(1,y,z)$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

We say that a polynomial $F$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ if it cannot be factored into a product of two non-constant polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that

> If $F(x,y,z)$ is a homogenous polynomial that is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$, then $f(y,z):=F(1,y,z)$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$.

If $x|F(x,y,z)$, then we can write $F(x,y,z)=xh(x,y,z)$, however as $F$ is assumed to be irreducible, $h(x,y,z)$ is forced to be a complex constant, say $h(x,y,z)=C$, and thus $F(x,y,z)=Cx$. Therefore, $f(y,z):=F(1,y,z)=C$ which is irreducible, because it cannot be factored into a product of two non-constant polynomials.

---

The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the case where $x\nmid F(x,y,z)$. I tried to argue by contradiction:

If $f(y,z)$ is reducible, then we can write $F(1,y,z)=f(y,z)=h(y,z)g(y,z)$ where $h,g$ are non-constants polynomials. Then, I tried to use the property of being homogenous: say $F$ is homogenous of degree $d$, then
\begin{align*}
&F(1,y,z)=h(y,z)g(y,z)\\
&\implies F\Bigg(1,\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)=h\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)g\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\ \ \text{for all}\ \ x\in\mathbb{C}^{*}\\
&\implies x^{d}F\Bigg(1,\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)=x^{d}h\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)g\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\ \ \text{for all}\ \ x\in\mathbb{C}^{*}\\
&\implies F(x,y,z)=x^{d}h\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)g\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\ \ \text{for all}\ \ x\in\mathbb{C}^{*}.
\end{align*}

But then I don't know what to do to find a contradiction. Is there anything like, the highest degree of $h$ plus the highest degree of $g$ is less than $d$, so we can factor out at least one $x$ in the RHS?

Thank you!

---

**Edit:**

As discussed, this post is a duplication of the link provided in the comment. After reading that post, I think that my proof above is basically done. The only confusion I had before was that if $d=\deg(g)+\deg(h)$. This is actually clear, because $F(1,y,z)=h(y,z)g(y,z)$, so $\deg(F)=d=\deg(hg)=\deg(g)+\deg(h)$, and then the proof can go through.

The following is a complete proof I wrote:

---

*Proof:*

Firstly, note that if $x\mid F(x,y,z)$, then we can write $F(x,y,z)=xh(x,y,z)$, but $F$ is irreducible, which forces $h(x,y,z)$ to be a constant, say $h(x,y,z)=C$. Then, $F(x,y,z)=Cx$ and thus $f(y,z):=F(1,y,z)=C$ which is clearly irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ because it cannot be factored into a product of two non-constant polynomials.

If $x\nmid F(x,y,z)$, then there must be some monomial summand of $F$ which contains no $x$. As all monomials in $F$ have the same degree $d$, the degree of $F(1,y,z)$ is also $d$ (the degree here is not homogenous degree, but is the highest degree among all the monomial summands in $F(1,y,z)$), because monomials in $F(x,y,z)$ that have $x-$term will not have $x-$term anymore in $F(1,y,z)$, so the degree of these monomials will decrease, but the degree of those monomials that do not have $x-$term will stay the same as $d$.

Hence, if $F(1,x,y)$ is not irreducible, i.e. $F(1,y,z)=g(y,z)h(y,z)$ for some non-constant polynomials $g,h\in\mathbb{C}[y,z]$, as $\deg(F)=d$, we must have $\deg(gh)=\deg(g)+\deg(h)=d$, and using the property of $F$ being homogenous, we have that
$$F(1,y,z)=g(y,z)h(y,z)\implies F\Bigg(1,\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)=g\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)h\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\ \ \text{for all}\ \ x\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$$
$$\implies x^{d}F\Bigg(1,\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)=x^{d}g\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)h\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\ \ \text{for all}\ \ x\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$$
$$\implies F(x,y,z)=x^{\deg(g)+\deg(h)}g\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)h\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\ \ \text{for all}\ \ x\in\mathbb{C}^{*}$$
$$\implies F(x,y,z)=x^{\deg(g)}g\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\cdot x^{\deg(h)}h\Bigg(\dfrac{y}{x},\dfrac{z}{x}\Bigg)\ \ \text{for all}\ \ x\in\mathbb{C}^{*}.$$

Note that both $x^{\deg(g)}g(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})$ and $x^{\deg(h)}(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})$ are polynomials, because for example, the highest degree of those monomial summands in $g$ is $\deg(g)$, so $x^{\deg(g)}$ will cancel the denominator, and for other monomial summands we have extra factors of $x$. But $F$ is assumed to be irreducible, and thus one of $x^{\deg(g)}g(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})$ or $x^{\deg(h)}(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})$ must be constant. This implies that $\deg(g)=0$ or $\deg(h)=0$ must hold, either of which will contradict the hypothesis that none of $g$ or $h$ are constant.

Hence, $F(1,y,z)$ must be irreducible

---

Comment: Slight typo there,  on your contradiction you said "if $f(y,z) is irreducible$,  pretty sure you meant is not!

Comment: @Alan yeah. Thank you. edited.

Comment: See [If I erase one of the variables in an irreducible homogeneous polynomial, it's still irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136035/if-i-erase-one-of-the-variables-in-an-irreducible-homogeneous-polynomial-its-s).

Comment: @dxiv nice suggestion. In fact I think my question is an exact duplication of the link you provide. I will close this post. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Glad it helped. Thought I'd leave you the choice to mark it as a duplicate, in case I missed some finer point.